# When do teams wear their away jerseys at international level?

Tags: rules, football, equipment

When will teams wear their away jerseys during the Euro Championships? Will France always wear their home jersey during the tournament?

For commercial purposes will all teams not want to play a match during a tournament in their away jersey at least once? I'm guessing that teams can wear their away jerseys if they want to as long as there is no objection from the officials. For example, Ireland wore their away jersey for three of their four matches in 1994:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E

Maybe the players liked the jersey more...

Answer (score 7):

The FIFA [Equipment Regulations](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/51/54/30/equipment_reg_26032010_en.pdf) state (Article 65):

> In the event that, in the opinion of the referee or Match Commissioner,
>   the Playing Equipment of the two opposing teams is not clearly distinguishable
>   for all Players, the Match Officials, spectators and media under the prevailing
>   conditions, such as weather and light, the referee or Match Commissioner may
>   instruct the host team to use Official Equipment and the visiting team to use
>   either its Reserve Equipment or a combination of both. In exceptional cases,
>   both teams may be asked to wear different Colours.

That answers the general question for "international matches". For more specific tournaments, The [2018 World Cup Regulations](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/59/22/68/regulationsfwc2018russia_short_e_v210415_neutral.pdf) (Section 24.4) contain similar language, but unhelpfully make no definition of "host team" that I can see. I can't see anything in the [2016 European Championship Regulations](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/03/92/81/2039281_DOWNLOAD.pdf) about kits.

Just to add to the confusion, there was at least one World Cup match, the [Brazil vs Sweden semifinal in 1994](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Jhg-oUKHMQ), when *both* teams wore their away kits. I can't find a reference at the moment, but my memory says that their was a coin toss to determine who would wear their home kit (as both teams traditionally wear yellow and blue), but the away kit of the losing team *still* clashed with the yellow and blue, so both teams played in their away kits.

Comment: i wonder also do all teams try to play at least one match in their away jersey for commercial purposes...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Philip Kendall's answer, just considering the France part:

Altough France is hosting the European Championship, that does not mean they are always considered the home team.

If you look at the [matches for group A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016#Group_A), you will see that France are the home team for their first and second game. Their third game in the group stage they are considered the away team and Switzerland as home team. If there would be any conflict there considering the colors, they would be asked to use their away (or even third) kit. Which probably won't be the case for the game against Switzerland.

**UEFA decides (apparently)**

Maybe interesting, earlier this week [UEFA](http://www.fcbarcelona.com/football/first-team/detail/article/fc-barcelona-and-atletico-madrid-to-play-with-second-kits) ordered both Barcelona and Atletico Madrid that they had to play in their away jerseys for good distinction, while they had played their league game both in their home jerseys. So UEFA might just look at the games and order the teams which kit to use *as they please*.

Comment: Good answer! I was actually wondering about why Barcelona were wearing their away jersey against Atletico even though they were playing at home.